# Add Identity column to all the tables in database Sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a database that is used to transfer data across the main production database when we import data from a third party.

I would like to add an `Identity` column to each table.

I know that the below SQL will do for a single table, how can I do it for all the tables in the database?

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do it one table at a time - there's no "magic" way to do it to all tables at once.

You can have SQL Server generate the T-SQL statements needed for that operation by inspecting the `sys.tables` catalog view - assuming you want to call that identity column `Id` for all tables:

```
SELECT
    t.NAME,
    'ALTER TABLE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.SCHEMA_ID) + '].[' + t.NAME +
    '] ADD Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL'
FROM
    sys.tables t
```

Now, copy & paste the resulting lines of this statement and execute those lines against your database - and you're done!

Comment: what about SP_MSFOREACHTABLE  "ALTER TABLE ? ADD SQL_ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY" just found it.

Answer (score 2):

U can use 'sp_MSforeachtable 'And add to Every table in your Database
just run this query:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable '
if not exists (select * from sys.columns 
           where object_id = object_id(''?'')
           and name = ''ColName'')
begin
ALTER TABLE ? ADD ColName <DataType> NULL ; // or NOT NULL DEFAULT 
<DefaultValue>;
end';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Azure SQL,This Stored Procedure is not available under programmability.
Either you can port it from your master database from your on-prem sql server.Or use this link to the run the stored procedure
https://gist.github.com/metaskills/893599